# when I pull images from mysql database it won't show because there are more than one image there. I only need to show the first image in every row

Tags: laravel

I'm getting the images from the database.but the problemis that it has multiple images in there under one id. i only need the 0th image where the pro_mc_id = 2

https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9CPz.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P74KA.jpg

I've been trying to put the images to a array and get the images. but i haven't had any success because i couldn't figure out the code

//Controller

```
public function read_data()
{
    $read = DB::select('SELECT * FROM `nm_product` WHERE pro_mc_id = 2 ');
    return view('test.box' , compact('read'));
}
```

//view

```
@foreach($read as $view_data)
        <div class="item">
            <section class="products">
                <div class="row row-clean">
                    <div class="a col-md-4">
                        <article>
                            <div class="info">
                                        <span class="add-favorite">
                                            <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-title="Add to favorites" data-title-added="Added to favorites list"><i class="icon icon-heart"></i></a>
                                        </span>
                                <span>
                                            <a href="#productid1" class="mfp-open" data-title="Quick wiew"><i class="icon icon-eye"></i></a>
                                        </span>
                            </div>
                            <div class="btn btn-add">
                                <i class="icon icon-cart"></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class="figure-grid">
                                <div class="image">
                                    <a href="#productid1" class="mfp-open">
                                        <img width="100" src="../public/assets/product/<?php echo $view_data->pro_Img ?>" />
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="text">
                                    <h2 class="title h5">
                                        <a href="product.html">{{ $view_data->pro_title }}</a>
                                    </h2>
                                    <sub>{{ $view_data->pro_price }}</sub>
                                    <sup>{{ $view_data->pro_disprice }}</sup>
                                    <span class="description clearfix">Gubergren amet dolor ea diam takimata consetetur facilisis blandit et aliquyam lorem ea duo labore diam sit et consetetur nulla</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </article>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>

@endforeach
```

Comment: use explode fuction and get array and write one more foreach loop and try it

Comment: I suggest you create one more table for images and relation hasmany for images its better way .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Code Hope its helpfull because explode function return array

```
    <?php
     $images = explode("/**/", $view_data->pro_Img);
       foreach ($images as $image) {
         $url = "../public/assets/product/".$image;
        ?>
           <img width="100" src="{{$url}}" />
        <?php
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: @AliÖzen how it return string because i have this  `1/**/2/**/3` and explde this its return 
$a = "1/**/2/**/3";
print_r (explode("/**/",$a));

output is :
`Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 )`

Comment: this returns with all the images on the database sir

Comment: yes just explode is return array, its correct. But head function return array[0]; thats string.

Comment: i am using head function it return 
I run your code but i got error `call to undefined function head()`

Comment: Thank you sir. this worked and i used a break; to get only the first image of every row

Answer (score 0):

create function to get first image

```
    function firstImage($seperator, $string){
    $separate = explode($seperator, $string);
    $extension = head($separate);

    return $extension ? $extension : false;
}
```

and use like this:

```
<img width="100" src="../public/assets/product/{{firstImage("/**/", $view_data->pro_Img)}}" />
```

Comment: I run your code but i got error `call to undefined function head()` ?